# Atomlessness of the Lindenbaum-Tarski $\sigma$-algebra of infinitary language $L_{\omega_1}$

Tags: logic, universal-algebra

Consider the Lindenbaum-Tarski $\sigma$-algebra $A$ of the infinitary language $L_{\omega_1}$ of propositional calculi. Since $L_{\omega_1}$ has $\omega_1$ propositional variables and allows disjunctions and conjunctions of all lengths strictly less than $\omega_1$, does that make $A$ atomless?

Answer (score 4):

*(You do specify the number of propositional atoms, but let me explain why that matters:)*

For simplicity, I'll assume that $0$ is $\top$ and $1$ is $\perp$ in the Lindenbaum algebra, so that an atom is a non-tautologous formula which doesn't strictly imply any formulas other than $\top$. Of course, swapping $0$ and $1$ here won't change things, so this doesn't really matter.

The answer to your question depends on how many propositional atoms you have. If you only have countably many - say, $(p_i)_{i\in \omega}$ - then $$(*)\quad\bigvee_{i\in\omega}p_i$$ is an infinitary propositional formula, and (up to semantic equivalence) the only thing it strictly implies is $\top$: one formula strictly implies another iff the latter is true in properly more valuations than the former, and $(*)$ is false in exactly one valuation.

If, however, you have uncountably many propositional atoms - as your question states - then the answer is **yes**: given a non-tautologous $\varphi$, let $p$ be a propositional atom not occurring in $\varphi$, and consider $\varphi\vee p$. Clearly $\varphi$ implies $\varphi\vee p$, but since $\varphi$ isn't a tautology we can $(i)$ find a valuation making $\varphi$ false and $p$ (hence $\varphi \vee p$) true since $p$ doesn't occur in $\varphi$, and $(ii)$ find a valuation making $\varphi$ and $p$ (hence, $\varphi\vee p$) both false - so $\varphi\vee p$ is neither a tautology nor a formula implying $\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you @Noah for your answer. May I ask: Is the free $\sigma$-algebra on $\omega$ free generators atomic? (It is not clear in my mind.)

Comment: @puzzled Yes. An atom - semantically speaking - is a sentence which **rules out exactly one valuation** (since then the only thing less than it is tautology). For a valuation $\sigma:\{p_i:i\in I\}\rightarrow\{\top,\perp\}$, let $\neg\sigma$ be the sentence saying that $\sigma$ doesn't hold: concretely, $\neg\sigma$ is an abbreviation for $$(\bigvee_{\sigma(p_i)=\top}\neg p_i)\wedge (\bigvee_{\sigma(p_i)=\perp}p_i).$$ Now given an arbitrary formula $\varphi$, let $Bad(\varphi)$ be the set of valuations making $\varphi$ false; we have $\varphi\equiv\bigwedge_{\sigma\in Bad(\varphi)}\neg\sigma$.

Comment: (Note that this means that every atom "looks like" the example I gave; in fact, it is the example I gave, up to replacing some propositional variables with their negations.) Incidentally, I just realized that I've made things ugly here: by putting "$\top$" on the bottom of my Lindenbaum algebra, I've made "$\vee$" the *meet* and "$\wedge$" the *join*. Ugh. Still, it should be clear what's going on here: every formula is equivalent to the meet in the Lindenbaum algebra presented as above (= the *disjunction*) of formulas which are atomic in that Lindenbaum algebra.